# How to create a pdf using html in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, express-handlebars

I am trying to convert html into pdf and i wanted to pass some dynamic value inside it and after that i wanted to generate a pdf when i am using this code where i have created an external html file and then i am able to convert the pdf here is the code of that

invoice.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Approve Page ,</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the pdf.js file

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const utils = require("util");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const hb = require("handlebars");
const readFile = utils.promisify(fs.readFile);

async function getTemplateHtml() {
  console.log("Loading template file in memory");
  try {
    const invoicePath = path.resolve("./invoice.html");
    return await readFile(invoicePath, "utf8");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function generatePdf() {
  let data = {};

  getTemplateHtml()
    .then(async (res) => {
      console.log("Compiing the template with handlebars");
      const template = hb.compile(res, { strict: true });

      const result = template(data);

      const html = result;

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.setContent(html);

      await page.pdf({ path: "invoice.pdf", format: "A4" });

      await browser.close();
      console.log("PDF Generated");
      return;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

generatePdf();
```

but i wanted to implement in this manner

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const utils = require("util");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const hb = require("handlebars");
const readFile = utils.promisify(fs.readFile);
const A = "invoice";
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Approve Page ,${A}</h2>
</body>
</html>
`;

async function getTemplateHtml() {
  console.log("Loading template file in memory");
  try {
    return await readFile(html, "text/html utf8");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function generatePdf() {
  let data = {};

  getTemplateHtml()
    .then(async (res) => {
      console.log("Compiing the template with handlebars");
      const template = hb.compile(res, { strict: true });

      const result = template(data);

      const html = result;

      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      await page.setContent(html);

      await page.pdf({ path: "invoice.pdf", format: "A4" });

      await browser.close();
      console.log("PDF Generated");
      return;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

generatePdf();
```

but getting this error

message:
'You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined',
name: 'Error',

Comment: Try to console.log res in then block, its probably undefined. Your getTemplateHtml() method must return a promise. It's probably pending.

Comment: yes it gives undefined but i am passing the html

Comment: You are  **not** passing in the html. Your code confusingly has two separate variables named `html` but it is confusing only to humans. Javascript is not confused because each `const` or `var` or `let` keyword tells javascript to create a new variable. Now, if two `const` with the same name appear in the same function it would throw an error but in cases like this where the const appear in different functions javascript will dutifully understand that the code is supposed to create a new variable even if the human writing the code may not realise it

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this problem with very less code but wanted to ask is it possible to convert it into base64 instead of creating a pdf file.
here is the solution

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const utils = require("util");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const hb = require("handlebars");
const readFile = utils.promisify(fs.readFile);
(async () => {
const A = "invoice";
const htmlContent = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Approve Page ,${A}</h2>
</body>
</html>
`;
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(htmlContent);
  await page.pdf({ path: "html.pdf", format: "A4" });

  await browser.close();
})();
```